# How to use set -x without showing stdout?

Tags: linux, bash, logging, sh

Within CI, I am running a bash script that calls many bash scripts.

```
./internals/declination/create "${RELEASE_VERSION}" "${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}" > /dev/null
```

This **doest not** disable the `stdout` returned by the script.

The Gitlabi-CI runners stop logging after 100MB of log, It says `Job's log exceeded limit of 10240000 bytes`.

I know the log script can only grow up.

How can I optimize the output log size?

I don't need to have all the `stdout`, I can have `stderr` but then it will be a long running script without information.

Is there a way to display the commands which is running like when doing `set -x`?

**Edit**

Reading the answers, I was not able to solve my issue. I need to add that **I am using nodejs** to run the bash script that run the long bash script.

This is how I call my node script within `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
scripts:
   - node my_script.js
```

Within `my_script.js`, I have:

```
exports.handler = () => {
  const ls = spawn('bash', [path.join(__dirname, 'release.sh')], { stdio: 'inherit' });
  ls.on('close', (code) => {
    if (code !== 0) {
      console.log(`ps process exited with code ${code}`);
      process.exitCode = code;
    }
  });
};
```

Within `my_script.sh`, I have:

```
./internals/declination/create "${RELEASE_VERSION}" "${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}" > /dev/null
```

Comment: Perhaps you can redirect stdout to `/dev/null`  - as in `cmd >/dev/null`? (Output to `stderr` should still be printed.)

Comment: Your command very definitely **does** redirect standard output. Perhaps you meant to write it doesn't redirect standard error, which is where e.g. `set -x` output goes?

Comment: stderr would most definitely go into the log. No CI system would discard stderr, because that's where all the useful diagnostics and error messages go.

Comment: The command I do in CI is a **node** script that will run the bash script that will execute this long running command. I have tried to use `> dev/null 2>&1` but then my CI when failing was not showing any errors. I have not been able to solve the issue.

Comment: I was having `ps process exited with code 2`. I have added my question with extra informations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can selectively redirect file handles with `exec`.

```
exec >stdout 2>stderr
```

This however loses the connection to the terminal, so there is no simple way to output anything to the terminal after this point.

You can instead duplicate a file handle with `m>&n` where `m` is the number of the file descriptor to duplicate and `n` is the number of the new one (choose a big number like 99 to not accidentally clobber an existing handle).

```
exec 98<&1  # stdout
exec 99<&2  # stderr
exec >/dev/null 2>&1
:
```

To re-enable output,

```
exec 1<&98 2<&99
```

If you redirected to a temporary file instead of `/dev/null` you could obviously now show the `tail` of those files to the caller.

```
tail -n 100 "$TMPDIR"/stdout "$TMPDIR"/stderr
```

(On a shared server, probably use `mktemp` to create a unique temporary directory at the beginning of your script; static hard-coded file names make it impossible to run two builds at the same time.)

As you usually can't predict where the next error will happen, probably put all of this in a wrapper script which performs the redirection, runs the build, and finally displays the tail end of the temporary log files. Some build servers probably want to see some signs of life in the log file every few minutes, so perhaps `tail` a few lines every once in a while in a loop, too.

On the other hand, if there is just a single build command, the whole build job's stdout and stderr can simply  be redirected to a log file, and you don't need to `exec` things back and forth. If you need to enable output *selectively* for portions of the script, use `exec` as above; but for wholesale redirection, just redirect the one command.

In summary, maybe your build script would look something like this.

```
#!/bin/sh

t=$(mktemp -t -d cibuild.XXXXXXXX) || exit

trap 'kill $buildpid; wait $buildpid; tail -n 500 "$t"/*; rm -rf "$t"' 0 1 2 3 5 15

# Your original commands here
${initial_process_wd}/internals/declination/create "${RELEASE_VERSION}" "${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}">"$t"/stdout 2>"$t"/stderr &

buildpid=$!
while kill -0 $buildpid; do
    sleep 180
    date
    tail -n 1 "$t"/*
done
wait
```

A flaw with this approach is that you lose timing information. A proper solution woud let you see when each line was produced, and display standard output and standard error intermixed in the order the messages were printed, perhaps with visible time stamps, and even with coloring hints (red time stamps for stderr?)

Comment: In your first example, do you mean `exec my_script.sh 2&>stderr` will instantly only show to my CI errors that this script throw?

Comment: I am not sure how to understand the example which duplicate the file handle, can you update your snipper with `my_script.sh` so I can see how exec is supposed to be used? Do i replace exec with the script name?

Comment: No, there are no additional parameters or anything. We are using a syntax of `exec` which *only* manipulates file descriptors. But I'll update with a concrete example.

Comment: Thanks for the concrete command. I have also updated my question because `> dev/null 2>&1` was not producing stdout nor stderr, do you still think your concrete example would work to forward to the ci process the errors?

Comment: The example redirects them to temporary files instead of `/dev/null`, and runs `tail` on them both at the end. I have assumed that the end of the log file will be the most interesting in the case of a failure, though the amount of lines you have to extract with `tail` is obviously pure speculation.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1

If your script will output the error message to stderr, you can ignore all output to stdout by using `command > /dev/null`, where `/dev/null` is a black hole that will take away any output to it.

Option 2

If there's any pattern on your error message, you can use `grep` to filter out those error messages.

---

Edit 1:

To show the command that is running, you can supply `-x` command to bash; therefore, your command will be

`bash -x ${initial_process_wd}/internals/declination/create "${RELEASE_VERSION}" "${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}" > /dev/null`

bash will print the command executed to stderr

---

Edit 2:

If you want to reduce the size of the output file, you can pass it to `gzip` by using `${initial_process_wd}/internals/declination/create "${RELEASE_VERSION}" "${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}" | gzip > logfile`.

To read the content of the logfile, you can use `zcat logfile`.

Comment: They are no pattern for error message. I can't send everything in `/dev/null` otherwise people can't look at the build log while it happens, is there a way to output the command executed like when you do `-x` and still forward the stdout to `/dev/null`?

Comment: do you mean `tee` ?